# Suppress "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" in Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app, console.log

I get the message "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" in the console when a webview in a Chrome Packaged App tries to load a non-existent local file. This is expected, because the program is supposed to check a couple of different location, starting with the local system and then switching to a remote server as a second try.

The problem is that there are a lot of these messages in the console, which makes it very difficult to use the console for anything else.

Is there a way to turn this message off?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can turn this off:

Click on the filter icon at the top of the console, and tick "Hide network messages".

You *can't*, however, prevent this error from happening at all: it's not generated by an uncaught exception in JS but is reported from the network stack of Chrome.

Comment: That worked. I assume that I am turning off other messages that I might like to see, but I guess I can live with that.

Comment: @Xan, But what if we're using serviceworker? Is there no way to catch suppress the `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` of `fetch()`? `fetch..catch` doesnt seem to do it.